# Trying to retrieve a date from an api and an error occured

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve and print out the date to my website from an api but some error has occurred and I cannot fix it, please kindly help.

I have already tried to remove the .split(" "), yes the error has been solved but the result shows "undefined" in the website instead of the exact date from the api.

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      allDownloadNewsTitle.push(response.data[i].title);
      var date = response.data[i].created_at.split(" ");
      console.log(date);
      var url = response.data[i].url;
      allDownloadNewsUrl.push(response.data[i].url);

      var inner = '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="card" style="width: 100%">'+
      '<div class="card-content-padding"><h3>' + response.data[i].title + 
      '</h3><br>' + date[0] + '<a style="float: right" class="link" id="' + i 
      + '" onclick="Download(this.id)"><span>MUAT TURUN>></span></a></div> 
      <div id="c' + i +  '"class="card-content-padding" style="display: none"> 
      </div></div></div>';

      $('#allNewsContainer').append(inner); 
    }
```

Comment: Probably response.data[i].created_at doesnt exist. Please check response.data and please confirm whether all the objects has created_at.

Comment: What does console.log(date); print?

Comment: You have missed a space in last `div` of `inner` between `id` and `class` - use this - `<div id="c' + i +  '" class="card-content-padding" style="display: none"> 
      </div></div></div>`

Comment: @AjayVarghese  "created_at": "2018-10-02 18:04:33" nope, the created_at is in the API

Comment: It means created_at is not present in response.data[i]. Try to print response and paste your console.log here

Comment: @ravibagul91 it say Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined. other than that is ok, after i remove `var date = response.data[i].created_at.split(" ");` this line the code work fine

Comment: `app.js:384 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:384)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: @WilliamNg I guess one more objects in response data is missing created_at.

Comment: comment that `split("")` line and `console.log(response.data[i])` and check every entry has `created_at` value. I am sure for one of the entry `created_at` is empty / not available.

Comment: @WilliamNg, can you provide your sample `response` data here to debug more efficiently ?

Comment: ah, i see, i think i got the answer, thanks ya, Ajay and Ravi

Comment: `"data": [
        {   "title": "Logo Rasmi PPPM",
            "description": "Logo Persatuan Pandu Puteri Malaysia yang digunakan secara rasmi ialah yang berbentuk bulat, berwarna hitam dan hanya outline yang digunakan. Hanya warna outline satu warna sahaja.",
            "path": "branch/1/files/1561705615-pppm logo.jpg",
            "url": "https://panduputeri.org.my/storage/branch/1/files/1561705615-pppm logo.jpg",
            "user": {
                "created_at": "2018-10-02 18:04:33",
                "updated_at": "2019-04-25 18:03:25",
            }
        },`

Comment: Is your problem is solved. You have `created_at` inside nested object called `user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your order of accessing of `created_at` is wrong

Try consoling out `response.data[i].created_at` and check whether it is showing your date or `undefined`.

If it shows date, then why don't you parse that date string into `javascript` date and do what you want to do
simply do this,

```
var date = new Date(response.data[i].created_at)
```

with this `date` object you can show date in what format you want.